# Two Keyboards with different layouts on Ubuntu 18

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I know similar questions have been asked already, but I did not find an answer to my problem. My Laptop has a German QWERTZ Keyboard Layout, as well as my pairing keyboard. My primary Keyboard is an US QWERTY keyboard. On Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS, I used the following script to change the Layout just for the US keyboard :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for id in $(xinput -list | grep 'Logitech USB Keyboard' | cut -f 2 | cut -d= -f 2); do
    setxkbmap -device $id -layout us -variant altgr-intl
done
```

I also set "org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard active" to 'false' to prevent Gnome from overwriting these settings. I'm not completely sure if I did anything else in ubuntu Gnome 16.04, but as far as I know this used to work fine.
After upgrading to Ubuntu 18 I find that the keyboard layout is changed back to the system-wide default (german qwertz) after some time. Does anyone know how I can prevent Gnome from doing that?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this can help you](http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_diff_layouts_for_2_keyboards.html)?

> First, use xinput to identify your keyboards.
>    Then, use setxkbmap to set the layout.
>
> My keyboards are id 10 (laptop integrated) and id 17 (external keyboard).
>
> Now, set my external keyboard to be Swedish layout, and my internal to Dvorak:
>
> ```
> $ setxkbmap -device 17 se  
> $ setxkbmap -device 10 dvorak
> ```